# An inequality for a recursively defined sequence of numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, sequences-and-series

Consider an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $r > 2$.

Set $y_0 = 1$ and $z_0 = 0$ and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ recursively define
$$y_n = y_{n-1} + (r-1) |x_{n} - z_{n-1}|^{r-2}$$
$$z_n = z_{n-1} + \text{sign}(x_n - z_{n-1}) \frac{|x_n - z_{n-1}|^{r-1}}{y_n}$$
where $\text{sign}(\cdot)$ is the usual sign function yielding 1 for positive and -1 for negative numbers.

I am trying to prove the following inequality

$$ |z_n| \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \max(1, |x_i|^{r-1}), \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. $$

**Some remarks**:

1. Extensive numerical tests for different $r$ and randomly generated $(x_n)$ suggest that the statement is true.
2. I tried to prove the inequality using induction, which did not work, since the lhs of the above inequality does not necessarily grow slower than the rhs *for every* $n$ (consider the case where $x_n=0$ and $z_{n-1} \neq 0$). Hence, it seems hard to prove the statement for $n$ solely based on the knowledge that it holds for $n-1$ (one would instead have to know by *how much* it holds).
3. It seems to me that the key is the fact that $y_n$ changes at most by an order of $|x_n-z_{n-1}|$ (due to the division by $y_n$) while the growth of the rhs is of order $x_n^{r-1}$ and $r-1>1$. However, until now I failed to make this precise even for specific choice of $r$ ($r=3$ seems to be an easy one) and $n$.

Any ideas on how to approach this would be very much appreciated.